# Do I have to Load/Get an entity before SaveOrUpdate in Nhibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, valueinjecter

in my ASP.NET MVC application I've separated the domain model from the view model.
I transform my entity in a viewmodel object so I can "feed" my views with only the data needed (I used valueinjecter for this purpose).
During the save process my controller gets back the viewmodel object, transforms it into a domain model entity and try to persist it with SaveOrUpdate.
I've noticed that if I try to update an existing record, Nhibernate considers it as a new object and forces an INSERT, even if my entity has a proper ID.
I haven't loaded (Get/Load) the entity before cause I would like to avoid to re-map all the fields again.
Is there anything I am doing wrong? What's the best way to achieve that?

***** - UPDATE - ***

My controller receives a User (ViewModel), validates it and tries to save it through a service layer as an entity:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, Models.User User)
{
...
var user = new Domain.User();
user.InjectFrom(User);
user.SetId(id);

user = this._SecurityService.SaveUser(user);

}
```

This is the service:

```
public Domain.User SaveUser(Domain.User User)
        {
            bool Result = false;

            if (this._ValidationEngine.IsValid(User))
            {
                using (_UnitOfWork)
                {
                    if (User.Code != Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        var user = this._UserRepository.Load(User.Code);
                        user.InjectFrom(User);
                        User = this._UserRepository.Update(user);
                    }
                    else {
                        User = this._UserRepository.Save(User);
                    }
                    Result = _UnitOfWork.Commit();
                }
            }
            return (User);
        }
```

I've got a concern about the fact that I have to transform my viewmodel/entity so many times. Now when I try to save a new User I got this message: **Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)**
Probably this is in some ways related to what Darin was telling me.
Are there any better ways to do what I am trying to do?

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that the error **"Row was updated or deleted..."** is caused by the fact that I have a version defined for my mappings. What I can understand is I need to have the **Id** and the **version** matching the entity I want to update.
I would like to understand how other people do these things with DDD + ASP.NET MVC + NHibernate ???

**SOLUTION**

All my entities have a version defined (I forgot to say, sorry):

```
<version name="Version" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="0">
   <column name="Version" not-null="true" />
</version>
```

As Ayende explained [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/15/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency.aspx), Nhibernate tries to update my entity with a query like this:

```
UPDATE Table SET field1 = 'bla', Version = (y+1) WHERE id = x AND Version = y
```

where y should be the version of my entity. Since I wasn't populating my entity with a version, it would generate an exception StaleObjectException.
I've added a version field to my viewmodel. I save it in a hidden field of my view together with the id.
My controller now receives a viewmodel with an Id and a version.
I inject these fields in my domain entity and let the repository save it (I don't reload my entity):

```
User = this._UserRepository.Update(user);
```

If I get a **StaleObjectException** exception it means that someone else has updated the DB row and I'll provide the user with some feedback.

Comment: try loading the entity and after re-map it (I know you don't want it this way), just try this and tell us if it works this way

Comment: I guess my problem is with the version.I've got <version name="Version" type="System.Int32 unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="Version" not-null="true" />
    </version>    defined in my mapping. I guess I have to find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have an Id and, therefore, know this is an update, use `session.Update` instead of `SaveOrUpdate`.

Comment: I am afraid I can't do that cause if I try to save my entity I get this message: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: caedb8a4-abce-4c6f-b171-9e7200cc7a37, of entity: BpReminders.Domain.User

Comment: That means the object is already loaded. Why aren't you updating the already-loaded object then?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake. What I am doing now is loading an entity from the repository and merging it with the one obtained from the controller. I still get an error "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)" when I try to insert. I'll update my original question with more infos.

Answer (score 4):

For `SaveOrUpdate` to work as expected you need to explicitly specify the `unsaved-value` attribute on your `<id>` mapping. So for example you would have:

```
<id unsaved-value="0" ...
```

and then issue a `SaveOrUpdate` call on a model which has the Id property assigned to a value different than `0` and it is going to `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`. So to answer your question, no, you don't need to manually issue a `SELECT` before `UPDATE`. `SaveOrUpdate` should do this behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks Daring. I guess that I have to use an empty Guid (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) if my id is type Guid, right?

Comment: @vandalo, try this: `unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"` (untested).

Comment: Thanks, again. What would you do, anyway? Should I rather load the entity from the DB and populate each field with the new entity in case I am trying to update? Are there any best-practices? Thanks again for your help.